# NHibernate join on aggregated count of self

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Hi I am new to NHibernate and having trouble doing a join on an aggregated set of self. I think showing the SQL I am trying to achieve might help:

The Data Looks Like this:

```
Message TABLE
ID  DIRECTION   BATCHID SEQUENCE    ISLASTINSEQUENCE        
1   Outbound    1       1           0   
2   Outbound    1       2           0       
3   Outbound    1       3           1
```

The query looks like this:

```
--Get all msgs with batchId where full sequence is ready
SELECT      *
FROM        [Message] M
JOIN        (
            --Group Msg on batchId and Count Sequence + cross ref using having
            SELECT      M.BatchId
            FROM        [Message] M
            JOIN        (
                        --Get BatchId of last msg in sequence
                        SELECT      BatchId,  Sequence as LastInSequence
                        FROM        [Message]
                        WHERE       Direction = 'Outbound' 
                        AND         IsEndOfSequence  = 1
                        ) M1 ON M.BatchId = M1.BatchId
            WHERE       Direction = 'Outbound'
            GROUP BY    M.BatchId, LastInSequence
            HAVING      count(1) = M1.LastInSequence
            ) B ON M.BatchId = B.BatchId
```

Basically I want to include batches where I have the full sequence

Here is may HNibernate Linq attempt:

```
var lastInSeqenceMsgs =
    from b in Query<Message>(x => x.Direction == MessageDirection.Outbound 
                             && x.IsEndOfSequence)
    select new {b.BatchId, LastInSequence = b.Sequence};

var fullSequenceBatchIds = 
    from outboundMessage in Query<Message>(x => x.Direction == 
                                           MessageDirection.Outbound)
    join lastInSequence in (lastInSeqenceMsgs)
        on outboundMessage.BatchId equals lastInSequence.BatchId
    group lastInSequence by new {lastInSequence.BatchId, lastInSequence.LastInSequence}
    into g
    where g.Count() == g.Key.LastInSequence
    select g.Key.BatchId;

var allMsgsFromWithCompleteSequences =
    from fullSequenceMessage in Query<Message>(x => x.Direction ==
                                               MessageDirection.Outbound)
    join test in (fullSequenceBatchIds) on
        fullSequenceMessage.BatchId equals test.BatchId
    select test;
```

To which it bombs on the second query (I evaluated the queries - not shown) with the following exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression' to type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.QuerySourceReferenceExpression'.

Of which I refined back to the join on self

```
var fullSequenceBatchIds =
        from outboundMessage in Query<Message>(x => x.Direction ==
                                                   MessageDirection.Outbound)
        join lastInSequence in (lastInSeqenceMsgs)
            on outboundMessage.BatchId equals lastInSequence.BatchId
        select outboundMessage;
```

To which I get the exception 
"Specified method is not supported."

I am getting brick imprints on my forehead, so some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In general I can just say that the nhibernate Linq provider does NOT support everything what Linq offers.

In addition, nhibernate does NOT support sub queries. It simply doesn't work and you have to work around it somehow.